# Convert XML to one dimensional list

Tags: xml, data-structures, modx

I wrote a script for MODX that reads an XML feed and parses it into placeholders, so the CMS can work with it in its templates.

It works fine with one level, as it takes all the parent elements children and puts them into placeholders like this:

```
<child>Britney</child> -> into placeholder [[+child]] -> displays as "Britney".
```

It works with attributes, too:

```
<child age="15">Britney</child> -> into placeholder [[+child.age]] -> displays as "15".
```

I am struggling to think of a way to get the grandchildren parsed in a nice way.

I dont want childrens elements to overwrite other elements.

```
<child age="15">
  <name>Britney</name>
  <toy>plastic crane</toy>
  <toy>wooden house</toy>
</child>
```

If I just append it to the current element, the second toy would overwrite the first one. Do I have to work with inserted indexes? Any idea?

Edit: I dont know what the elements might be that are available in the XML file.

Comment: No advices without seeing code, that you use to parse xml and set placeholders. Can you show it?

Answer (score 0):

It's little hard task since you don't have explicit XML format. In this case you need to predict all cases according to [XML Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/).

I can give you my thoughts of that, how can you start:

```
<child age="15">
  <name>Britney</name>
  <toy>plastic crane</toy>
  <toy>wooden house</toy>
</child>

<child age="18">
  <name>Bob</name>
  <toy>toysoldier</toy>
  <toy>teddybear</toy>
</child>
```

1. [[+child.1]] => ""
2. [[+child.1._age]] => 15
3. [[+child.1.name]] => "Britney"
4. [[+child.2.name]] => "Bob"
5. [[+child.1.toy]] => "plastic crane,wooden house"
6. [[+child.1.toy.2]] => "wooden house"
7. [[+child._length]] => 2

If you want to advise just form your example, i think **[[+child.toy.2]]** or **[[+child.toy_2]]** will be enough.